# uiwebview taking time to load html javascript file

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, html, uiwebview

I am using `UIWebview` to load html5 animations using `javascript` but its taking around 10-15 seconds before it starts loading page.

```
 newdemo = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(185.0, 216.0, 180, 180)];
    newdemo.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    newdemo.opaque = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:newdemo];

    url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"A" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO];
    [newdemo stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function (lib, img, cjs)"];
    req1=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];
```

I am using following code for loading `html` page in my `UIWebView` "newdemo" and have tried to implement this code in `viewDidLoad` but no fast response and also tried to use this code in `viewWillAppear` but no success.
Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Try to first load the html and call the javascipt function afterwards.

Comment: @FD_ I have done that way also still no success.

Comment: [newdemo loadRequest:req1];
when I try to reload uiwebview using the above code, html page opens instantaneously without any delay but I want this thing to happen at the first load itself with 1-2 sec delay allowed.

Comment: in my case webview was taking time to load because I had set the property of 'preloadjS' of my js in html file to be "false" now i have set it to "true" and my uiwebview works perfectly.

So I think that if js animations are to be used make sure you preload them while declaring in your html file.

Comment: Great you found a solution.
BTW, you could pack the above comment is an answer. This way, the question would no longer appear a being unsolved and you could earn up votes from fellow readers.